# Variable declaration from one class to another

Tags: java

the below codes are working fine(individually) i just want to pass letter[i] value from FindDrive class to Ziputils input file location such that i can zip pendrive data automatically.

**FindDrive Class**

```
package com.prosper;

import java.io.File;


public class FindDrive
{
/**
 * Application Entry Point
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String[] letters = new String[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"};
    File[] drives = new File[letters.length];
    boolean[] isDrive = new boolean[letters.length];

    // init the file objects and the initial drive state
    for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
        {
        drives[i] = new File(letters[i]+":/");

        isDrive[i] = drives[i].canRead();
        }

     System.out.println("FindDrive: waiting for devices...");

     // loop indefinitely
     while(true)
        {
        // check each drive 
        for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
            {
            boolean pluggedIn = drives[i].canRead();

            // if the state has changed output a message
            if ( pluggedIn != isDrive[i] )
                {
                if ( pluggedIn ){
                    System.out.println("Drive "+letters[i]+" has been plugged in");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Drive "+letters[i]+" has been unplugged");

                isDrive[i] = pluggedIn;
                }
            }


        // wait before looping
        try { Thread.sleep(100); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { /* do nothing */ }

        }
    }

}
```

**The ZipUtils Class**

```
package com.prosper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ZipUtils {

    private List <String> fileList;
    private static final String OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE = "E:\\appu\\Folder.zip";
    private static final String SOURCE_FOLDER = "E:\\appu\\"; //SourceFolder 

    public ZipUtils() {
        fileList = new ArrayList < String > ();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZipUtils appZip = new ZipUtils();
        appZip.generateFileList(new File(SOURCE_FOLDER));
        appZip.zipIt(OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE);
    }

    public void zipIt(String zipFile) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        String source = new File(SOURCE_FOLDER).getName();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ZipOutputStream zos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
            zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            System.out.println("Output to Zip : " + zipFile);
            FileInputStream in = null;

            for (String file: this.fileList) {
                System.out.println("File Added : " + file);
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(source + File.separator + file);
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                try {
                    in = new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER + File.separator + file);
                    int len;
                    while ((len = in .read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                }
            }

            zos.closeEntry();
            System.out.println("Folder successfully compressed");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                zos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void generateFileList(File node) {
        // add file only
        if (node.isFile()) {
            fileList.add(generateZipEntry(node.toString()));
        }

        if (node.isDirectory()) {
            String[] subNote = node.list();
            for (String filename: subNote) {
                generateFileList(new File(node, filename));
            }
        }
    }

    private String generateZipEntry(String file) {
        return file.substring(SOURCE_FOLDER.length() + 1, file.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a `String[] letters` field in ZipUtils, create a setter for this field and pass your `letters` array into this setter of instance of `ZipUtils` class.

Comment: Thnx @IvanPronin for suggestion, Can you edit the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data from one class to another, you can do the following:

1) Create an object of the class in your FindDrive class:

```
 ZipUtils utils = new ZipUtils();
```

2)  Pass the value to the method of that class:

```
utils.zipIt(letter[i])
```

I have inserted a few statements, which create a new object of ZipUtils class and call the method, however I do suggest you looking into **Dependency Injection** as well, if you want to improve your code quality here

```
package com.prosper;
import java.io.File;

public class FindDrive {
/**
 * Application Entry Point
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] letters = new String[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"H", "I"};
        ZipUtils utils;
        File[] drives = new File[letters.length];
        boolean[] isDrive = new boolean[letters.length];

        // init the file objects and the initial drive state
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i) {
             drives[i] = new File(letters[i] + ":/");
             isDrive[i] = drives[i].canRead();
        }
        System.out.println("FindDrive: waiting for devices...");

        // loop indefinitely
        while (true) {
            // check each drive
            for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i) {
                boolean pluggedIn = drives[i].canRead();
                utils = new ZipUtils();
                utils.changeDirectory(letters[i]);
                // if the state has changed output a message
                    if (pluggedIn != isDrive[i]) {
                        if (pluggedIn) {
                             System.out.println("Drive " + letters[i] + " has been plugged in");
                        } else {
                             System.out.println("Drive " + letters[i] + " has been unplugged");
                        }
                        isDrive[i] = pluggedIn;
                   }
            }

           // wait before looping
           try {
               Thread.sleep(100);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* do nothing */ }
       }
   }
}
```

To make changes to SOURCE_FOLDER after declaration, you need to make sure its not a constant i.e it is not final.
Add a method in ZipUtils:

```
 private static String source_folder = "E:\\appu\\"; //SourceFolder 

 public void changeDirectory(String zip) {
     source_folder = zip + ":\\";
 }
```

Comment: Thanx for the Answer @slal but can you edit the code,i am getting error after applying changes. It will be big help for me,

Comment: Ok, I will edit your code and paste in another answer, so that other people will still be able to view your original question

Comment: but how i will pass the drive location "private static final String SOURCE_FOLDER = ":\\";  " in ZipUtils class

Comment: which method do you want to pass the drive location to?

Comment: i want to pass letters[i] value from FindDrive t0 ZipUtills  SOURCE_FOLDER directory such that the code will zip the pendrive data

Comment: The code should be as modular as possible, so you should not merge the code if you want to follow good Object Oriented Practices. But, if you really need to you can do it very easily, just add the methods in ZipUtils to FindDrive or add the methods of these classes to another class. I am adding the code to edit the SOURCE_FOLDER to my answer

Comment: Its Showing Error that Source_Folder Can not be assigned.

Comment: I was editing that, now it should not, your SOURCE_FOLDER was a constant before. Also notice I have changed the code in FindDrive as ```utils.changeDirectory(letters[i]);```

Comment: but its taking E:\\appu\\ data to zip not taking pendrive data

Comment: can you describe a little more in detail what are you expecting

Comment: FindDrive class will detect the usb inserted and it will pass the usb directory to Ziputils program such that it will take usb directory as a source directory and zip the content of usb in specific folder defined by user as an output.  Sorry for all the confussion.

Comment: If I understand right, you are looking for an append method. i.e you want it to be something like this : ```"E:\\appu\\<letter[i]>"```

Comment: i want something like "<letter[i]>:\\" this such that it will take pendrive location

Comment: That would be simple string manipulation, ```source_folder = source_folder+":\\"```. Check my edited answer

Comment: it throwing an error that Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.prosper.ZipUtils.generateFileList(ZipUtils.java:86)
 at com.prosper.ZipUtils.generateFileList(ZipUtils.java:87)
 at com.prosper.ZipUtils.main(ZipUtils.java:33)

Comment: I will come  back to the problem tomorrow

Comment: could you solve the problem?or are you still getting the error?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I was getting the error.I think the ZipUtil program is not properly zip files of folder.